# TeXworks bite+TAB

Tags: texworks, auto-completion

I like to use TeXworks as a text editor for latex documents. I just have a question with a keyboard shortcut. When I type bite + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I've got the following result :

```
\begin{itemize}
\item

\end{itemize}•
```

I'm just wondering why there is a dot at the end. Does anyone has an answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bullets added by the autocompletion feature in TeXworks are there for navigational purposes. By hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> the cursor will move to the position of the bullet, and the next bullet will be selected. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> you jump to the previous bullet.

This allows you to quickly jump out the the environment or whatever it is you've added.

Comment: @Torbjørn_T. Ok, now the next question : is it possible to remove that bullet ?

Comment: @PAC You would have to edit the auto-completion files I guess. On Linux you can find them in `~/.TeXworks/completion` (the location of the directory depends on OS, see [TeXworks wiki](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Locating_and_customizing_TeXworks_resources)). Through editing these files you can also add custom completions.

Comment: It's option tab on macOS, for those who are interested.